# How can I delete every item in my list?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I remove everything on my listview with my clickfunction below?
Now it only removes the first item in the list and not every item.
This is my code:

```
async void OnButtonClickedRemoveEverything (object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        theGuestListMembers ourItem = null;  //theGuestListMembers is our Class.

        foreach (theGuestListMembers c in ourEventList) {   //oureventlist = this is Our List.

                ourItem = c;
        }
```

// . listID is a public string that gets the personal "info" from a user (the objectID). so I guess the "ourItem.listID" is our problem because I only get 1 persons objectID i guess not everyone from the list?

```
        if(ourItem != null)
        {
            parseAPI.deleteTheGuestList 
            (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString (), ourItem.listID);    
            ourEventList.Remove (ourItem);

            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = null;  //name of our list

            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourEventList; 
        }

        Navigation.PopAsync ();
    }
```

My database where i get info.

```
var getItems = await parseAPI.getOurGuestList (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString (), owner);
            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = null;
            ourEventList = new List<theGuestListMembers> ();

            foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

                ourEventList.Add (new theGuestListMembers () { 
                    listID = currentItem ["objectId"].ToString (),
                    theHeadName = currentItem ["YourName"].ToString ()

                });

        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Your `foreach` loop assigns each element (one at a time) to the variable `ourItem`. When it is done processing, `ourItem` will reference the last item in the list. Were you assuming that the `foreach` was building up a new list of items to remove? In the end `ourItem` will reference one element and that element will be removed by the `Remove` method in your `if` statement.

Comment: I am trying to remove every item on the list. But as you say above it only takes one as of now. And I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What is the type of your list? If it's a `List` you can use `Clear`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hm okay. Where would I put that and can I use to to my database as well to clear "every item" created?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If all you want to do is clear the items from your list, you can remove all of the code in your method except for `ourEventList.Clear()`. No this won't do anything to clear items from your database.

Comment: When you click my function above, I want everythiing on the list to get removed, both on the app and database.

Comment: You need to show us some of your database code. Up until now, you never mentioned a database. How did you get items in the database? Did you call a stored procedure?

Comment: i show when i delete the database, give me a sec and I will update the post with my database as well.

Comment: now its there on my mainpost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the items from the list, you can use `ourEventList.Clear()` or `ourEventList.RemoveAll(ourItem => ourItem != null)`

If you want to do something fancier, you can use this function:

```
private bool removeItem(theGuestListMember ourItem)
{
    if (ourItem == null) return false;

    parseAPI.deleteTheGuestList(ourItem);
    return true;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
async private void OnButtonClickedRemoveEverything(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ourEventList.RemoveAll(ourItem => removeItem(ourItem);

   EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourEventList; 
   Navigation.PopAsync ();    
}
```

Comment: and how would I remove the items on my database?

Comment: What type of database? A relational database? Well, you could write a stored procedure and call that.

Comment: i cant find the "c" in my boolfunction

Comment: What is it doing? Is it looping through all of the elements? Is the list empty? Has anything removed from the database?

Comment: the "c" is the problem

Comment: I fixed that. Replace `c` with `ourItem`.

Comment: ok the database doesnt like the code: parseAPI.deleteTheGuestList; 

error: (only assigment call, increment,await etc etc)

Comment: Fixed it. Forgot to pass `ourItem` to the method.

Comment: damn it, still get a error. (the best overloaded method match for "parse.delete.."has some invalid arguments

Comment: Thanks alot for being patient with me :) Learned alot from this fix.

Comment: No problem! Just keep in mind that those last few errors you should have been able to fix on your own.